# SwiftUI updating UI with high frequency data

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, observable, grand-central-dispatch, combine

I'm trying to update the main view with high frequency data coming from separate background thread.
I've created two tabviews and in case of slow update rate I can change the view. But in another case the UI doesn't react. I've observed this behavior only on real device, in the simulator works everything fine.

The while loop is still representing an imu, just to keep it simple.

Did someone any idea how to fix this issue?

Many thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var loop : Loop
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView{
        
            VStack {
                Text("Content View")
                LoopView()
            }.tabItem{
                  VStack{
                      Text("tab1")
                      Image(systemName: "car")
                }
                
            }
            
            Text("second view").tabItem{
                                    VStack{
                                        Text("tab2")
                                        Image(systemName: "star")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class Loop : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var i : Int
    
    func startLoop() {
        while true {
            print("i = \(self.i)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.i += 1
            }

            //sleep(1) // comment out to simulate worst case
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.startLoop()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why do you want to update UI so often? What kind of data will it be?

Comment: I had a similar issue with high frequency UI updates and the key was to use child views that not all the time the Full view will be refreshed. Maybe this can help you as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540602/navigationbar-toolbar-button-not-working-reliable-when-state-variable-refres

Comment: Endless loop without delay is just an example. The sensor (IMU) are updating with 60 Hz, the UI may be updated slower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to separate updating storage of frequency data from represented UI part, so storage receives/contains actual real data, but UI part update as soon as you only want (0.5 sec, 1 sec, 5 secs, etc.)

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
import Combine
class Loop : ObservableObject {
    private var storage: Int = 0
    private var counter = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    @Published var i : Int = 0   // only for UI

    func startLoop() {
        while true {
            storage += 1     // update storage 
            counter.send(storage) // publish event
        }
    }

    private var subscriber: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        subscriber = counter
            .throttle(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background), latest: true) // drop in background
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)  // only latest result
            .sink { [weak self] (value) in    // on @pawello2222 comment
               self?.i = value
            }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.startLoop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use `sink(receiveValue:)` for classes to avoid a retain cycle. See https://forums.swift.org/t/does-assign-to-produce-memory-leaks/29546

Comment: I've texted your code quickly and it works by me. I'm going to understand now what do the combine class exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried solving that problem by using combine?
If your ui is updating too fast you can for example collect some data in combine in a kind of buffer and then after the buffer is full you can push it to your view. Another approach would be to debounce the input for a specific delay and then push only the last update to your view. For example lets say you have your published variable i that constantly updates it value. You could introduce the following viewmodel:

```
class Loop: ObservableObject {
    @Published var i: Int = 0
    @Published var updatedVariable: Int = 0
    private var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $i
          .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
          .sink { [weak self] value in 
              self?.updatedVariable = value
          }
          .store(in: &bag)
        startLoop()
    }

    func startLoop() {
        while true {
            print("i = \(self.i)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.i += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you update your ui only every 0.5 seconds if you use the updatedVariable instead the i variable.

Comment: It's recommended to use `sink(receiveValue:)` for classes to avoid a retain cycle. See https://forums.swift.org/t/does-assign-to-produce-memory-leaks/29546